# replacing a pattern in a column value with a column value

Tags: r, api

after an hour or so skimming trough stackoverflow and trying out different things I've decided to make another query.

I made a data frame [ picture 1 ] in which I basically inserted a vector with the same length as the df containing a URL used to access an API's data.

Hereby I added the "FLAVOURS" text in the URL as a "pattern trigger" for gsub to replace this word with the column value which I will replace later as flavors.

What i ended up with was a df with 2 columns one with the URL used for the API and one with all the flavors. What i wanted to do now is insert the flavors [column 2] into the URL so it would become e.g:

"http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/ZlWfxSa/searchdata/flavors/Earthy"

***So what I would like to happen*** is the pattern "FLAVOUR" to be replaced by the column 2 data in a row wise fashion.

I've tried using gsub on its own, or in combination with rowwise() but I've been getting errors out of them, or they do something I didn't expect at all.

[image: Dataframe i currently have, API key is covered up in the URL.]

*I'm still new to both R and making stackoverflow posts so please do give me pointers if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can use any of the apply family of functions to do this. If your dataframe is called `df` and the first two column are `a` and `b` you can do :

```
df$a <- mapply(function(x, y) sub('FLAVOURS', y, x), df$a, df$b)
```

However, `stringr` has a vectorised function `str_replace`.

```
df$a <- stringr::str_replace(df$a, 'FLAVOURS', df$b)
```

---

Another base R option would be to treat column `a` as file paths and use `dirpath` to extract the path until the last `'/'` and `paste` it with `b` column.

```
df$a <- paste(dirname(df$a), df$b, sep = '/')
```

Comment: I tried the first 2 , the third is a bit over my head as i dont understand it. The first 2 gave me these errors: > flavors_site_df[1]<- stringr::str_replace(flavors_site_df[1], 'FLAVOURS', flavors_site_df[2])
Error: `replacement` must be a character vector
> flavors_site_df[1] <- Map(function(x, y) sub('FLAVOURS', y, x), flavors_site_df[1], flavors_site_df[2])
argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.  Sorry if its unreadable, i do not know how to inserts text collums with propper spacing in comments

Comment: @DesmondDjoemena Make sure you have columns of type character. Run `df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.character)` to turn first two columns to character. Also if you are referencing columns by position and not by name use double brackets instead of one like this `df[[1]] <- stringr::str_replace(df[[1]], 'FLAVOURS', df[[2]])`. While asking question it is better to add data to your post which we can use instead of sharing an image which we cannot use but only see. If the data is confidential, you can generate fake dataset which is similar to your original data.

Comment: ```{r}flavors_df <- fromJSON("http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/àpi_key/searchdata/flavors", flatten = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame()
flavors_site_list_df<- rep("http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/api_key/searchdata/flavors/FLAVORS", length(flavors_df))
flavors_site_df<- cbind(flavors_site_list_df, flavors_df)
flavors_site_df[[1]]<- stringr::str_replace(flavors_site_df[[1]], 'FLAVORS', flavors_site_df[[2]])``` it worked. Many thanks for your help and patience for a newcomer like me.